# how to save users data though with cakephp v2.0 and webtechnich facebook plugin?

Tags: facebook, cakephp, callback, save

Im very new to cake and the plugin (facebook plugin from webtechnick).

what is the best way (easy, effective) to save the user data (facebook_id, token, etc), when (or after?) users logging in?

I tried to use afterFacebookLogin with the array variable, "$facebook_user", as a parameter, but I have no idea why the callback method dose not work at all.

so could some kind bakers tell me the way?

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In your AppController add or modify your beforeFilter():

```
function beforeFilter(){
        $fbUser = $this->Connect->user();
        $Facebook = new FB();
        if($fbUser){
            $this->set('facebook_user', $fbUser);
            $user = $this->Auth->user();
            $this->set('user', $user);
            if($this->Auth->user('id') && !$user['User']['has_details'] && !$user['User']['email']){
                $this->loadModel('User');
                $user['User']['username'] = $fbUser['username'];
                $user['User']['first_name'] = $fbUser['first_name'];
                $user['User']['last_name'] = $fbUser['last_name'];
                $user['User']['link'] = $fbUser['link'];
                $user['User']['gender'] = $fbUser['gender'];
                $user['User']['email'] = $fbUser['email'];
                $user['User']['has_details'] = true;
                if($this->User->save($user, array('validate' => false))){
                    $this->Session->write('Auth.User.has_details', true);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: it seems working now. thank you!
but this code means user data will be saved everytime whatever page they click on, right?
I want to save the information only after their logging in.

Comment: move the user details check block to the user login function